# how to get the unique records from the table in sql server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, group-by

i have 3 tables

crossarticle_article -- Where article details are stored.

crossarticle_category -- Where category details are stored.

crossarticle_articletocategory -- Where article and category mappings are stored.. (this is because an article could exist in more than one category)

now i want to get the article based on the joins of all the three tables, but the problem is if i do that, i would get the repeated article title, as same article could be in more than one category, so no use of group by too. i need the crossarticle_category join because the category name exists in that table. and even if i skip that table, still crossarticle_articletocategory has the mapping for category and article. so still i would get repeated article title, can anyone suggest me some query so that i do not get repeated article titles.

```
****************************UPDATED QUESTION*************************
```

http://www.prosoundnetwork.com/uploadedImages/ProAudioReview/Forum/PAR_Forum/Sample2/sqlquery.png

you can right click and open in new window, to see the proper view, in the resultset you can see the titles are repeated.

Comment: What do you want to do with the categories in the results -- get a count?  A comma separated list?  What exactly are you expecting if you have more than one category?

Comment: Also, you should post the details of your tables -- or some of them -- so we can write sql that will work.

Comment: Can you post what you would like the output to be? A sample would be great.

Comment: @Abbas - see my example below for how to get an alphabetical comma separated list with one row per article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this will work:

```
  SELECT TOP 5 CA.Id AS ArticleID, CA.Title as ArticleTitle,
     stuff( (SELECT ', '+CC.Name
             FROM  CrossArticle_ArticleToCategory A2C 
             INNER JOIN CrossArticle_Category CC ON A2C.CategoryId = CC.Id
             WHERE A2C.ArticleId = CA.Id
             ORDER BY CC.Name
             FOR XML PATH ('')
            ), 1, 2, '') as Categories
  FROM CrossArticle_Article CA
```

This will give you one row per article with a comma list of categories.
It will look like this (I tested so it is correct):

```
ArticleID   Article Title              Categories 
5685        AlkjTechv                  Hardware
5684        Show Report...             Gear, News
5683        Radi-something introduces  Gear, News
```

I only have 3 answers because you only gave example data for 3 results.

As a side note: this is much faster than a custom aggregate.

---

If what the categories are does not matter than a select like this will give you all the titles:

```
  SELECT TOP 5 CA.Id AS ArticleID, CA.Title as ArticleTitle,
  FROM CrossArticle_Article CA
```

Comment: Actually i want only record for that article, coz i will be having a link on that, which could be for any one section at a time. so top 1 latest record for specific category

Comment: hi hogan, i guess this will work for me, just a question, can i just get the first category, before ","

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, you want just one category? What is the point of having more than one category in your database then?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `distinct` modifier: `SELECT distinct article_title`.

Comment: this does not include the category -- part of the original request.

Comment: This will work only if you're getting unique titles.  If you want to (somehow) include the category(ies) the article belongs to, it become somewhat more complex.

Comment: @Hogan It might be me, but I don't see him asking for a thing like that. If he wants something else he should make his question more detailed.

Comment: i have detailed my question, can you guys please have a look

Comment: If you want to make it so that the categories get concatenated then you'll have to install a custom aggregate function: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182741.aspx (see at the bottom of the page).

Comment: @ChristopherS - No you don't need that, you can use the `XML` trick I show below.